# How do I fix rvmrc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I set up rvm (and .rvmrc file) not properly, therefore whenever I go the directory of my RoR project and type `rails s` or any other `rails` command, I'll get the error of

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

and I have to type `rvm use 1.9.3-p392` to fix it.

**.rvmrc file contains**

```
environment_id="ruby-1.9.3-p392@project1"
if [[ -d "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments"
  && -s "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id" ]]
then
  \. "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/environments/$environment_id"
  for __hook in "${rvm_path:-$HOME/.rvm}/hooks/after_use"*
  do
    if [[ -f "${__hook}" && -x "${__hook}" && -s "${__hook}" ]]
    then \. "${__hook}" || true
    fi
  done
  unset __hook
else
  # If the environment file has not yet been created, use the RVM CLI to select.
  rvm --create  "$environment_id" || {
    echo "Failed to create RVM environment '${environment_id}'."
    return 1
  }
fi
```

Comment: can you post content of your .rvmrc file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try
    rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p391 --default

Answer (score 1):

.rvmrc in the newest version of RVM is deprecated. It should work but try new syntax:

put to .ruby-version file just:

```
1.9.3-p392
```

Additionaly you can define .ruby-gemset with

```
yourgemsetname
```

Answer (score 1):

Post your rvmrc file in order to get some help.
If you want to check a look at other's project rvmrc file you can take a look at octopress [here](https://github.com/jerryshen/octopress/blob/master/.rvmrc). Also you can take a look at [rvmrc docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/) if you haven't already looked.

The message you've got is from the autocomplete ubuntu/debian projects, meaning that it can't found the rails command, so it suggests the packages you can install to get it.
Probably you havent loaded the rvm environment. You can load it via:

> source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

and then check if it works.